# StreamSource - which module for module-info?

Tags: java, eclipse, module

Using *javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource* in a very simple program.
Using Eclipse and Java 13.
Configured *Java Build Path Modulepath* to contain *JRE SystemLibrary [JavaSE-13]* .
I have added *requires java.base;* to *module-info.java*.

But still: Eclipse cannot compile that class:
*The type javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource is not accessible*

What do I miss?

Comment: For a _"very simple program"_ you do not need a `module-info.java`, only when using `jlink`. Otherwise, in the line with the `import` statement use the Quick Fix (Ctrl+1) _Add 'requires java.xml' to module-info.java_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented by [`StreamSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html), that class is in the [`java.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/module-summary.html) module:

[image: screenshot of StreamSource Javadoc]

Which means to use `StreamSource` in your module you need the following module-info:

```
module <your-module-name> {
  requires java.xml;
  // other requires, exports, opens, uses, and provides directives (as needed)
}
```

Note you don't need to include `requires java.base;` as that module is implicitly required by every module, similar to how you don't need to import classes from the `java.lang` package.